# Extract maximum and minimum using awk by with groupby

Tags: awk, max

i'm new to this site and trying to learn awk. i'm trying to find the maximum value of field5, grouping by years, and also months..

for every month (of a year), printing just the line with the maximum of probability

input file: (comma separated)

```
year,month,lat,lng,probability  
0,0,40,331,1.00000    
0,2,38,334,0.01111  
0,2,38,334,0.05511  
0,4,38,335,0.06667  
0,8,38,336,0.16667  
1,2,39,334,0.12222  
1,2,39,335,0.04444  
1,4,39,336,0.02222  
1,4,40,333,0.14444  
1,4,40,334,0.12222  
2,6,40,335,0.06667  
2,6,40,336,0.14444
```

output file desired

```
months,lat,lng  
2,38,334  
4,38,335  
8,38,336  
14,40,333  
16,40,336
```

thank you everyone for the help

Comment: StackOverflow is not a script-writing service. Please show what you've tried

Comment: i just need someone to guide me, i never asked for the full script

my problem is that i can't write a script with these two groups, by year and by month, i did alot of researchs on the internet, but no results

Comment: Mistakes happen - we understand ..... Show us your attempts, no matter if the script works poorly

Comment: i tried this code for example   
`awk -F, '$1==1  $2==1 ${x+=$5;}END{print x}' example.csv`  
to see if the sum of probability of the month 1 and year 1, but don't work, the syntax is absolutely new for me, i'm lost

Comment: where do the 14, 16 values in the first column come from?

Comment: hello Karakfa, 14 and 16 are for the months, because i removed years, to be simple for the groupby

Comment: Why is `4,38,335` included and `0,40,331` is not? Why is `30,40,336` not included?

Comment: the first 4 is the month (fourth month), the position is 38 (lat) and 335(lgt)
0,40,331 i forget to include it, it's just an example of what i want as a output. i think the script for the first column is `$2+($1*12)` 
but how to do it for every line.. that's my question partielly, when i will have only month, i can group my data by month and try to find the max..
sorry for my bad english.. i'm not really fluent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are inconsistencies in your example. If by 'group' you mean a group defined by `$1,$2` needs to have more than one entry, that explains why `0,40,331` is not included. But then why is `4,38,335` included?

Anyway, you ask for a *start* and here it is:

```
$ awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
        NR==1{print $2,$3,$4; next}
        NR==FNR && FNR>1 { 
            if ($5>max[$1 OFS $2]) max[$1 OFS $2]=$5
            next
      } 
      max[$1 OFS $2]==$5 { print $1*12+$2,$3,$4} 
 ' file file
```

Prints:

```
month,lat,lng
0,40,331
2,38,334
4,38,335
8,38,336
14,39,334
16,40,333
30,40,336
```

Notice that the script traverses the file twice (by using `file` twice on the command line). The first time is to find the max of the group defined by `$1,$2` and the second time to print that line.

If you only want *groups* included, count them:

```
$ awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
      NR==1{print $2,$3,$4; next}
      NR==FNR && FNR>1 { 
            cnt[$1 OFS $2]++
            if ($5>max[$1 OFS $2]) max[$1 OFS $2]=$5
            next
      } 
      max[$1 OFS $2]==$5 && cnt[$1 OFS $2]>1 { print $1*12+$2,$3,$4} 
 ' file file

month,lat,lng
2,38,334
14,39,334
16,40,333
30,40,336
```

I acknowledge that is different than your example, but I think your example needs more explanation.

Comment: thank you very much it was really helpful to me!   
i admit that my example was not really explicit, it's my first time here on stackoverflow, i did'nt know much exactly how it works!
  
The first output (of your script) is what i'm trying to find, i've tried you code, did't work for me, i had as results only "month lat lng" an not the other lines    

but the code was helpful to me because i've finally the code to convert the first and second field to months only, and i think with that, i can do the rest of the code  
  
thanks again @dawg

Answer (score 0):

thank you all, and thanks @dawg for the help

i want to give a feedback of my final code:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
        NR==1{print "months",$3,$4; next}
        NR==FNR && FNR>1 {
            if ($5>max[$1,$2]) 
        max[$1,$2]=$5
                next
      } 

      {if (max[$1,$2] == $5)
        print $1*12+$2,$3,$4;}' example.csv example.csv `
```